# check if a contact installed an app android (like whatsapp/Viber)

Tags: android

I am building an application where users are able to interact with the contacts of their device(using phoneNumber) who have this application installed (pretty much how Whatsapp, Viber function)

Now this functionality can be achieved by a function `getContacts()`

Storing all app registrations on my server
From the app, sending all contact to server and receiving in server response, the registered contacts
However, this leads to problems of synchronization in cases where contacts are added/deleted or existing ones are updated

For this, my knowledge guides me to alternatives

Everytime app is launched, call this `getContacts()` method so that the data retrieved is fresh
Not sure if this is the method used by Whatsapp & viber, its achievable but a lot of unnecessary processing during each launch
Have a background Service poll the server through `getContacts()` method
This can keep contacts synchronized
However, this will not refresh changes instantaneously. In Whatsapp, if I change the name of a contact, it is reflected almost instantanouesly
Register a `ContentObserver` on `ContactsContract.CONTENT_URI`
( Really not much of an idea on this )
Please provide your insights